# Shiny app crashes on Mac in RStudio

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, shiny

When I run a Shiny App either an example or my own it starts a new window, freezes and then aborts. It tries to listening to a local port then starts a new session.

**Details of my system:**

My R version: 3.1.3 on MacOS Maverick

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.12.0 Rcpp_0.11.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.8    htmltools_0.2.6 httpuv_1.3.2    mime_0.3        R6_2.0.1
[6] tools_3.1.3     xtable_1.7-4

**What I tried so far:**

From different internet forums I found a lot of suggestions:

- I reinstalled Rstudio.
- I updated all the packages
- Tried this:   install.packages(c("Rcpp", "httpuv", "shiny"))
- Loaded Rcpp and httpuv separately
- tried to run like this runApp('app1',host="127.0.0.1",port = 3894)

  // tried other ports as well.

But nothing works. 
(Please note that, I don't know whether it's relevant but GoogleVis Demo worked on my RStudio.)

Comment: Could you post a simple example of the code for one of the Shiny Apps that didn't work?  It may be as simple as the syntax having changed from the version of Shiny supported on R 3.1.3 and in the current version of Shiny (which the examples might be based on).  In which case, you would solve it by: a) updating R, or b) changing your code syntax to match the older version of Shiny.

Answer (score 2):

@roboticman

My recommendation is first to test and confirm R is correctly setup on your machine. We can then move to harness a Shiny demonstration application and confirm if that works.

> > https://technophobe01.shinyapps.io/WorldBank/

#### First step:

Can you please run the following command via R, this should download and install shiny and its dependencies...

> > > install.packages("shiny", dependencies = TRUE)

If things work after this, great. If not, well, then let's check your R configuration:

#### Validate R Install

To check your configuration, my recommendation is you launch R on your machine and run the following tests and post back the output.

```
> R
> sessionInfo()
Sys.setenv(LC_COLLATE = "C", LC_TIME = "C", LANGUAGE = "en")
library("tools")
testInstalledBasic("both")
testInstalledPackages(scope = "base")
testInstalledPackages(scope = "recommended")
testInstalledBasic("internet")
```

Once you post the output of the above command set, we can move to work through the example '*World Bank*', and see if we can determine the problem.

Take care

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
runExample("01_hello", host = "0.0.0.0", port = 9999).
```

`runApp` will also work:

```
shiny::runApp(host = "127.0.0.1", port = 9999)
```